# Inserting Id from another table to current table access form

Tags: mysql, sql, database, vba, ms-access

I have an access form that adds transactions. when you hit the add transaction button. it will create the transaction in the Transactions Table, along with the Guest information in the Guest table.

I want to take that GuestID from Guest and store it in the Transaction.GuestID field. 
linking the data for each Transaction to the correct Guest.

Idea 1

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Transaction (RoomNumber,GuestID)" _

& " VALUES ('" & RoomNum & "','SELECT Max([GuestID]) FROM [Guest]' );"
```

Idea 2

```
, SELECT GuestID FROM [Guest] WHERE GuestID =( SELECT max([GuestID]) FROM Guest )  ) ;"
```

currently, Idea1 will create the new data for Transaction and Guest but does now add any value in Transaction/GuestID

Thank you for your time in advance

Comment: idea 2 will give you what you already have in  `SELECT max([GuestID]) FROM Guest )  `

Comment: `'SELECT Max([GuestID]) FROM [Guest]'` needs to be `(SELECT Max([GuestID]) FROM [Guest])`

Comment: '" & RoomNum & "', ( SELECT Max([GuestID]) FROM [Guest] ) );"  is this what you are refering to. because this returns syntax errors.

Comment: what are the errors?  Can you show the data types in both tables also.

Comment: Query input must contain at least one table or query.                   and the datatype for Guest.GuestID is AutoNumber  ,  and Transaction.GuestID is Number

Comment: what is the sql just the bit from the comma???  show the generated sql pls.

Comment: CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Transaction (CheckInDate,CheckOutDate,[Amount],RoomNumber,GuestID)" _
& " VALUES (#" & Me.CheckIn & "#,#" & Me.CheckIn & "#,'" & Me.total & "','" & RoomNum & "', ( SELECT Max([GuestID]) FROM [Guest] ) );"

Comment: transaction cant be used as a reserved word of sql try [Transaction]

Comment: i have added the Brackets ,however the transaction script does insert the only thing omited is the GuestID